# how can i change div position so that it shows up ontop of column

Tags: javascript, html, css

**What I want:** I have a gridview, if user hoverover col#4, than I want to show div (custom tooltip). if user hover out side of col#4 than hide div

**Issue:** How can I style so that `ToolTipPanel` shows up on top of col#4? so that it looks more of a tooltip rather than some random div ontop of file. Note gridview & col size can change depending on screensize or data size

**Html** - I have a panel which I am using as Custom ToolTip and a gridview

```
        <asp:Panel ID="ToolTipPanel" class="ToolTipPanelC">
            <div style="border:1px solid black; background:color:yellow;">
                <p>Random text for tooltip</p>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>

 <asp:GridView  ...>
   ...
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="col4" SortExpression="col4">
       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="col4S" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col4") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   ...
</asp:GridView>
```

**Back-end Code - here call js functions**

```
  Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
        e.Row.Cells(4).Attributes("onmouseover") = "javascript:showToolTip();"
        e.Row.Cells(4).Attributes("onmouseout") = "javascript:hideToolTip();"
    End If


End Sub
```

**Javascript** Hide or show div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showToolTip() {
        var x = document.getElementById("ToolTipPanel");
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
    function hideToolTip() {
        var x = document.getElementById("ToolTipPanel");
        x.style.display = "none";
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to get the final computed location of the column and set the panel's position based on that location. This is how a lot of tooltip libraries work. In fact, using a Tooltip library could be a good idea in your case too.

In any case, these will likely be relevant to your attempts:

- [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)
- [`MouseEvent.clientX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX) and [`MouseEvent.clientY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientY)
- [`window.scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) and [`window.scrollLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft)
- You may also need to disable [`Pointer Events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) with CSS if you decide to hide your panel differently than using `display: none`…

Answer (score 0):

One way could be using *Absolute Positioning*

You'd have to keep the `div` as a child of the column and then use `position: absolute` and `top: -Ypx` where `Y` would be the height of the div such that it always stays on top of the column

Refer: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-the-position-property-in-css-to-align-elements-d8f49c403a26